# Выгрузить чужую OpenSource библиотеку себе

Tags: java, android

Вот таким макаром добавил себе библиотеку:

```
compile ('com.github.florent37:materialviewpager:1.2.0@aar'){
    transitive = true
}
```

Добавил себе всё что нужно, всё хорошо работает.
Я хочу добавить свою реализацию одного метода этой библиотеки.
Хотел просто наследовать свой класс от исходного и там переопределить метод. Наследовал, переопределить никак, потому что исходный класс использует другой класс, в котором мне и нужно переопределить метод. А этот класс, в котором метод нужно переопределить, берётся из главного класса вот так:

```
public PagerSlidingTabStrip getPagerTitleStrip() {
    return (PagerSlidingTabStrip) pagerTitleStripContainer.findViewById(R.id.materialviewpager_pagerTitleStrip);
}
```

А переменная `pagerTitleStripContainer` в этом классе `private` и доступа к ней нет. И `get` метода тоже нет. Да и `set` нету.

Может есть какие-то способы реализовать метод? Помогите пожалуйста.
Нужно переопределить метод:

```
private void addTab(final int position, CharSequence title, View tabView)
```

Который находится в классе `PagerSlidingTabStrip`

Comment: Как вариант, можете клонировать себе гит-репозиторий https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager, внести правку и пересобрать и, если думаете что это нужно всем, то сделать pull-request

Comment: Reflection API в помощь

Comment: Если все что вам нужно  - это получить доступ к приватной переменной , то проще всего наверное будет использовать Reflection Api, как было предложено выше. Если добавите код и опишете что нужно сделать могу написать метод.